# prompt available function list after input dot symbol

Tags: jedi, autocompletion

I would like emacs show all available functions after input dot symbol, for example, after input re., emacs show search, findall, ... then I can select one of them.

I have installed auto-complete mode and jedi-mode, but it only show function definitions after I input the function name.

Maybe I do not config it correctly?

Comment: Wouldn't `company` be more appropriate for what you want to do?

Answer (score 1):

from [this](http://tkf.github.io/emacs-jedi/released/) document:

```
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'jedi:setup)
(setq jedi:setup-keys t)                      ; optional
(setq jedi:complete-on-dot t)                 ; optional
```